# Mac OS 10.10 ignoring Openvpn DNS settings

Tags: macos, vpn, dns, openvpn

Running Mac OS 10.10.  Setup a openvpn connection and put the DNS servers to be used with the VPN connection under VPN Profile->Advanced->DNS.  When I connect, it only uses the the DNS server pulled form the wifi dhcp.  It ignores the DNS servers listed under the openvpn config.

This setup use to work on OS 10.7<.  Is there something different in the newer versions that has to be done get it to change your DNS servers when connecting to a VPN aside from manually doing it?

Answer (score 1):

insert `setenv opt block-outside-dns` into the .ovpn file